# jquery ui datepicker onselect inst target

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, instance, onselect

So I have what I think is a pretty basic question but I cant for the life of me figure it out. How do you reference the selected date element (dom) once clicked. I have tried this:

```
$("#eventCalendar").datepicker({
 onSelect: function(dateText,inst){  
  var activeDateObj = $("#eventCalendar").find('.ui-state-active');  
 } 
});
```

This returns an object but I think it references the previously selected element; as in the class has not yet been applied to the new element. I'm really surprised the inst object doesn't contain some reference to the clicked element. I got this method to work by wrapping a quick timeout around the variable declaration but this is pretty dirty and I want to know if there is a better way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `this` refers to the associated input field.

Comment: sorry. i meant $("#eventCalendar").find('.ui-state-active'); does that make sense?

Comment: what you want to do after getting the selected element?

Comment: use the delay function in jquery for the timeout thing u mentioned however a bit more information of what yo are trying to do is needed. that returned obj is most likely the selected date. or todays date element if none selected.

Comment: Well originally I wanted an event popup box to appear when a user clicked on a certain date (i have that all setup). but now that i think about it.. on hover makes more sense. How can I attach an event to each date block?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to put an event on each day? ie 1-31 of jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Response to comments on OP.

From what I can tell the calendar seems to reload the table containing the days of the month each time a day is selected, it does this when you change months also.

If you use `.live('click',function(){...})` this should allow you to attach your function.

For the selector something like this might be the best

```
 //attached to an input, not displayed inline.
$('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker table.ui-datepicker-calendar td[class!=ui-state-disabled]')
```

You now just have to work out which date was selected.

Comment: Yea this is not a bad idea. not sure why i missed this lol.. But I'm wondering if its possible to accomplish the same thing with the "beforeShow" event or maybe "beforeShowDay" event?

Comment: beforeShowDay would allow you to show a tooltip which you could use to say something about the specific day but neither of those two events will allow you to set a function on the click event of the day, from what I understand.

I'm not really sure what you want, but beforeShowDay might be enough for want you want.

Comment: OK then that wont work. I have a custom build tooltip that needs to follow the cursor when you hover over specific dates. The method in this answer should do the trick, it just seems a bit crude to me. I wonder why they don't have some sort of build-in method for this.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

```
//...
onSelect: function(date, inst) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log($('a.ui-state-active')); // clicked day's DOM-Element
    }, 0);
}
```

The setTimeout-Wrapper will queue the stuff after the calendar got refreshed.